# Realtime Data Flow on data nodes visualization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, real-time, visualization

Hi I am working on realtime data visualization where I have some nodes and edges and I want to show realtime data flow between that nodes using some visualization. I want visualization like this example: [Netflix Visualization](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/vizceral-open-source-acc0c32113fe)

They are using "vizceral". I want something like this library which will provide me this kind of visualization.

I am getting my data from server using socket.io

Comment: _"I want"_ No actual question appears at original post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you want something "like" this library and [this library is open sourced](https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral), what makes it so that you cannot use it?